# asdf-install missing component

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I'm having a weird issue with asdf-install.

```
* (require :asdf-install)

("ASDF-INSTALL")
* (asdf-install:install :split-sequence)
...

Installing /Users/zcai/.sbcl/SPLIT-SEQUENCE.asdf-install-tmp in     /Users/zcai/.sbcl/site/,/Users/zcai/.sbcl/systems/
split-sequence/README.cCLan-install
split-sequence/split-sequence.asd
split-sequence/split-sequence.lisp

debugger invoked on a ASDF:MISSING-COMPONENT:
  Component "split-sequence" not found

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY] Retry installation
  1: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((LAMBDA ()))
0]
```

The problem is that whatever package I'm trying to install, asdf-install will complain component with that package name is missing.

I'm not sure if this is a configuration problem or something else. I'm running 1.0.49 sbcl on OS X 10.6.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I tried on a Ubuntu machine running sbcl 1.0.40. It does not have the same issue, maybe it's a bug of asdf that comes with sbcl 1.0.49?

**UPDATE 2**

I did a

```
(asdf-install:install :asdf-install)
```

Then it was able to install many packages without the earlier problem. But when I try to install :cffi, a dependency called "rf" case the same problem. Then I had to restart slime, and the installation will finish without a problem. Looks like it is something wrong with asdf-install then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- do NOT use ASDF-INSTALL. ASDF-INSTALL is obsolete and unmaintained.

2- Use Quicklisp.